# How do I unit test that two namespaces cannot overlap?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm trying to make sure two keyspaces can never overlap. My approach is to append `_users`, `_devices`, `_objects` ... to the end of the keys to separate keys into non-overlapping keyspaces. They must never overlap, because that is a security risk and can lead to lost data.

Keyspaces are subsets of possible keys. For example, if you're writing files to disk, files with random names but different file extensions will never collide. Same thing if you generate one filename from lowercase letters and one from uppercase letters (assuming the file system is case-sensitive). This problem also arises in key/value stores, and many other areas.

How do I unit test that they don't overlap?

Comment: What's your language of choice?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I just need the general approach. Any C-language, python, lisp or haskell-like language works.

Comment: I'm a Java developer with lots of unit test experience, but your question is confusing. What is a keyspace? So.. I disagree, please add tags.

Comment: Are you referring to sanity checks upon ingest data?

Comment: Clarified what I mean by a keyspace. If they overlap, and you have e.g. in a key/value store, the key `%username%_profile` which contains the profile picture, and the key `%username%` which contains a json object of other data about the user, and someone registers the username `my_profile`, it'll collide with a user called `my`.